# HTTP client for multithreaded application

Tags: java, http, asynchronous

I'm implementing Java-based HTTP bot for performance testing purposes. Can anyone suggest Java HTTP client library, suitable for multithreaded environment.

It looks like standard answer is [Apache HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), but it's synchronous and it seems to me I need some async solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You should use HTTP Client's [`ThreadSafeClientConnManager`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html). It will allow you to reuse one instance of `HttpClient` across threads. See [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e638) guide for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that implements what you want (based on apache httpclient):

```
public class ApacheHttpTransportImpl extends BaseHttpTransport {
    private final CloseableHttpClient threadSafeClient;
    private final IdleConnectionMonitorThread monitor;  
    public ApacheHttpTransportImpl() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        super(config);
        ConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new PlainConnectionSocketFactory();
        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create().register("http", socketFactory).build();
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
        cm.setMaxTotal(256);
        cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(64);
        RequestConfig clientConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(2000)
.setSocketTimeout(1000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(2000).build();
        threadSafeClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(clientConfig).setConnectionManager(cm).build();
        monitor = new IdleConnectionMonitorThread(cm, this);
        monitor.setDaemon(true);
        monitor.start();
    }
    public CloseableHttpClient get() {
        return threadSafeClient;
    }

    private static class IdleConnectionMonitorThread extends Thread {
        private final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm;
        private final BlockingQueue<Stop> stopSignal = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Stop>(1);
        private final ApacheHttpTransportImpl cp;
        private static class Stop {
            private final BlockingQueue<Stop> stop = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Stop>(1);
            public void stopped() {
                stop.add(this);
            }
            public void waitForStopped() throws InterruptedException {
                stop.take();
            }
        }
        IdleConnectionMonitorThread(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm, ApacheHttpTransportImpl cp) {
            super();
            this.cm = cm;
            this.cp = cp;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Stop stopRequest;
                while ((stopRequest = stopSignal.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) == null) {
                    cm.closeExpiredConnections();
                    cm.closeIdleConnections(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                stopRequest.stopped();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

And here is how it can be used:

```
ApacheHttpTransportImpl transport = new ApacheHttpTransportImpl();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = transpot.get().execute(httpGet);
```

Also, you can take a look on [Unirest](http://unirest.io) - it is very simple in using, although it is based on apache httpclient as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that bugs me about the Apache Client.  If you only need something simple, you can just use URL and openConnection()

Comment: I don't need something simple, I need something that offers good performance and stability :-).

Comment: It looks like you can use that HTTPClient in a thread-safe way:
https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html